# Which python IDE shows all class attributes?

Tags: python, ide

Is there a python IDE or code editor that shows all the data attributes (both class and instance variables) of all the classes used in a script? (IDLE has a class browser that shows the names of all the classes and their methods. But it does not show the data attributes.)

**Edit** Can a linter do the job? Can pylint be configured to show the attributes?

Comment: spyder might, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: How do you expect for it to work? You can write script to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

but it's not free you can use 30 day free and after that buy it

Answer (score 0):

**Use the force**

1. Emacs + `jedi`.

   pip install jedi sexpdata epc

And in Emacs

```
package-install RET anaconda-mode RET
```

More information [here](https://github.com/proofit404/anaconda-mode)

2. VS Code + `jedi`.

Install VS Code then [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python).

3. Atom + `jedi`

Install Atom then [this](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-python).

There's also a Vim + `jedi` if that's your jam.

If you're more of an IDE person you can always download Eclipse and search the marketplace for PyDev.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess I will go with option 3.

Comment: autocomplete-python is not working in Atom. When I install it, nothing happens in the code.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions? I'm an Emacs user so I won't be of much help about configuring Atom.

Comment: The package should work as-is, without requiring setting changes. But it isn't. Since I haven't started using Atom, I'm open to Emacs. With Emacs, do I always need a virtual environment to be active for autocomplete to work. (In Windows, pip works only inside a virtual environment.)

Comment: You just need to have `jedi`, `sexpdata` and `epc` installed in your virtualenvs for `jedi` to work.

Comment: Could get the Atom editor to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602603/atom-ide-autocomplete-python-not-working