# Atom IDE autocomplete-python not working

Tags: python, atom-editor

I have just installed the Atom IDE and the package autocomplete-python (on Windows). But the package is not working. Do I have to make any setting changes? (I have disabled autocomplete-plus and autocomplete-snippets).

Do I need to separately install Jedi?

Answer (score 20):

If autocomplete-python in Atom not working with Python 3.7
In windows, go to:

`C:\Users\username\.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\jedi\parser`

Or in linux:

`cd ~/.atom/packages/autocomplete-python/lib/jedi/parser`

Duplicate file named "grammar3.6.txt" and change it to "grammar3.7.txt"

It's worked for me with python 3.7!

Comment: The same fix worked for me for the package: `autocomplete-python-jedi` a fork of `autocomplete-python` Atom package

Comment: Can confirm this works for python3.8 as well. Just make a copy of the file and name it grammar3.8.txt.

Comment: thank you, this is the best post in the history of the internet

Answer (score 13):

It worked when I enabled autocomplete-plus. It seems autocomplete-plus is required for autocomplete-python to work. (I had initially followed a youtube video in which autocomplete-plus and -snippets were disabled and then autocomplete-python was installed.)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, in order to fix it I added python executable path installed package setting and it worked.

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe;C:\Python27\Scripts\".
```

In my case I had PyCharm, Anaconda and Python 2.7 was installed on my system and while using `atom` editior I was not accessing any of the environment, was working on just a plain .py files saved on my desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I was have same problem,
my Atom autocomplete-python not working , I went to:

```
C:\Users\username\.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\jedi\parser
```

and because my Python was 3.8 I was created "grammar3.8.txt" too.
Then everything was right And the atom was working properly

Comment: Till these days the autocomplete-python didn't update this file. So I did exactly what you did and it did the job. I assume that it is not perfect, because I copied the grammer file of 3.7, but at least it functions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I had the same issue and resolved it by adding a path to my site-packages for one of my virtual environments in the settings.

1. On the toolbar, go to File-> Settings -> packages.
2. Find your autocomplete-python package.
3. Go to the settings of the autocomplete-python package.
4. Scroll down to "Extra Paths For Packages".
5. Copy and paste a path location to your site packages.

e.g:
C:\Users\my_username\Miniconda3\envs\my_env_name\Lib\site-packages

6. Celebrate :)

Answer (score 0):

Same for me. I followed the previous answer but could not find autocomplete-plus (June 2018). I installed autocomplete and now both packages work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, enabling autocomplete-plus didn't help.

It worked when I changed the Python version that I am using from Python 3.7
to Python 3.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem while trying to use the django-atom autocomplete snippet and after reading different articles on it here is how I go about it.

1. Go to the directory of the installed autocomplete package, in this case here:

   C:\Users\user.atom\packages\django-atom
2. Go to the snippet folder and you'll find a .cson file, right click and open it with an editor in this case here is the directory:

   C:\Users\user.atom\packages\django-atom\snippets
3. Copy everything inside the file and go back to the snippets.cson file in .atom parent directory, in this case here:
   C:\Users\user.atom
4. Right click and open the snippets file with an editor, scroll down and paste everything you copied earlier into the file then save.
5. Bro, now you can enjoy your beautiful snippets.